# Transforming an Informix query to Oracle?

Tags: oracle, join, transformation, informix

I have a query that doesn't work; can you help me with the transformation?

The original Informix query that I want to transform to Oracle.

```
SELECT DISTINCT table3.no_cev,   
         table1.literal,   
         table1.colid,   
         table2.repid,   
         table2.valor,   
         table2.indicador,   
         '',   
         '',   
         table2.origen,   
         table2.codi,  
         table2.no_cia,
         table2.num_dcca,
         table2.no_aprof,
         table2.no_compta
    FROM table1,   
         OUTER table2,   
         table3  
   WHERE ( table1.colid  = table2.colid) and  
         ( table1.grupid  = table2.grupid) and  
         ( table3.no_cev  = table2.no_cev) and  
         ( ( table1.grupid = 2) AND  
         ( table2.cod_exp = 99609 ) AND  
         ( table2.indicador = 'S' ) ) AND  
         ( table3.num_dcca = 1); 
         ( table3.codest = 76695);
```

My transformation of the query from Informix to Oracle — but it looks like it doesn't work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT table3.no_cev,
  table1.literal,
  table1.colid,
  table2.repid,
  table2.valor,
  table2.indicador,
  '',
  '',
  table2.origen,
  table2.codi,
  table2.no_cia,
  table2.num_dcca,
  table2.no_aprof,
  table2.no_compta
FROM table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN (table2
RIGHT OUTER JOIN table3
ON table3.no_cev        = table2.no_cev)
ON (( table1.colid      = table2.colid)
AND ( table1.grupid     = table2.grupid))
WHERE ( ( table1.grupid = '2' )
AND ( table2.cod_exp    = '99609' )
AND ( table2.indicador  = 'S' ) )
AND ( table3.num_dcca   = '1')
AND ( table3.codest     = '76695');
```

Comment: OT: forget about rewriting it into "Oracle". Rewrite it into ISO SQL - which is also supported by Oracle.

Comment: Your original query ends with the lines `( table3.num_dcca = 1);` and `( table3.codest = 76695);`. It isn't clear whether the first semicolon should be replaced by AND or whether the condition on `table3.codest` should be dropped.  You should omit the two empty/null fields in the SELECT data; you could also drop a number of the columns from `table2` — candidates for being dropped include all the columns not otherwise named in the query, such as `repid`, `valor`, `origen`, `codi`, `no_cia`, `no_aprof`, `no_compta`. Keep one of them; you don't really need more. An outline schema would help too.

Comment: The Informix old-style OUTER join is a complex critter, and doesn't necessarily have a simple translation to modern standard SQL (and hence to Oracle, etc).  You should first aim to replicate the revised query using INNER JOIN and OUTER JOIN in Informix (assuming you aren't using an archaic version of Informix without support for explicit OUTER JOIN, etc).  The extra level of parentheses in `WHERE ( ( table1.grupid = '2' )
AND ( table2.cod_exp    = '99609' )
AND ( table2.indicador  = 'S' ) )` doesn't alter the query — they could be dropped.

Comment: Why are the values in the WHERE clause of the Informix written without quotes around the numbers (`( ( table1.grupid = 2) AND  
         ( table2.cod_exp = 99609 ) AND  
         ( table2.indicador = 'S' ) ) AND  
         ( table3.num_dcca = 1); 
         ( table3.codest = 76695);`) and written in quotes in the Oracle rewrite (`WHERE ( ( table1.grupid = '2' )
AND ( table2.cod_exp    = '99609' )
AND ( table2.indicador  = 'S' ) )
AND ( table3.num_dcca   = '1')
AND ( table3.codest     = '76695');`)?  This is confusing; what are the types of the columns?

Comment: Sample data and the expected result from the sample data would be helpful too.

Comment: Your mistake is mainly the table2 conditions in the `WHERE` clause. In an outer join you keep rows without a match by adding nulls. You are dismissing these outer-joined rows, however, by demanding that the cod_exp be 99609 and the indicador be 'S'. Move these conditions to the `ON` clause of the table2 outer join to fix this. With this little change your query should work.

Comment: Then, however, it is suggested not to use right outer joins at all for the lack of readability. So move the table3 join before the table2 join. This converts the table3 join to a cross join (because table1 and table3 are unrelated). Please see my answer on this.

Answer (score 0):

You have joined the table with ON clause at wrong place in the code.

Corrected your code now as following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    TABLE3.NO_CEV,
    TABLE1.LITERAL,
    TABLE1.COLID,
    TABLE2.REPID,
    TABLE2.VALOR,
    TABLE2.INDICADOR,
    '',
    '',
    TABLE2.ORIGEN,
    TABLE2.CODI,
    TABLE2.NO_CIA,
    TABLE2.NUM_DCCA,
    TABLE2.NO_APROF,
    TABLE2.NO_COMPTA
FROM
    TABLE1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    -- ( -- removed this bracket 
     TABLE2 ON ( ( TABLE1.COLID = TABLE2.COLID )
                                AND ( TABLE1.GRUPID = TABLE2.GRUPID ) ) -- added this ON here
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN TABLE3 ON TABLE3.NO_CEV = TABLE2.NO_CEV 
    -- ) -- removed this bracket
WHERE
     TABLE1.GRUPID = '2' 
    AND  TABLE2.COD_EXP = '99609' 
    AND  TABLE2.INDICADOR = 'S' 
    AND  TABLE3.NUM_DCCA = '1' 
    AND  TABLE3.CODEST = '76695' ; -- no need of extra brackets
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Are you familiar with the behaviour of the old Informix-style OUTER joins?  They're unlike any other you've encountered (if you've encountered them).  See my answer for an illustration of what the result of the original Informix query is, and how to simulate it in standard SQL.

Comment: Cool. I am not aware about that. Thanks for the information

Answer (score 0):

It makes life unnecessarily difficult for people who would like to help you when you don't include a more or less minimal outline schema for the tables used in your query, and some sample data, and the expected results.  Further, you seem to have converted numbers (integers) in the original Informix query into strings in the Oracle query.  It is not clear why.  Again, the schema would help explain what's going on.

As I noted in the comments, you should omit the two empty/null fields in the select-list; you could also drop a number of the columns from `table2` — candidates for being dropped include all the columns not otherwise named in the query, such as `repid`, `valor`, `origen`, `codi`, `no_cia`, `no_aprof`, `no_compta`. Keep one or two of them; you don't really need more.  However, I've preserved all the named columns in the sample data.

#### Schema and data

Here is some Informix SQL that appears to match the tables and columns in the query shown in the question.  In case of doubt, the column was made into an INTEGER column.  All the columns are qualified with NOT NULL.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table1;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table2;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table3;

CREATE TABLE table1
(
    grupid      INTEGER NOT NULL,       -- 2
    literal     VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    colid       INTEGER NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE table2
(
    grupid      INTEGER NOT NULL,
    no_cev      INTEGER NOT NULL,
    colid       INTEGER NOT NULL,
    repid       INTEGER NOT NULL,
    valor       INTEGER NOT NULL,
    indicador   CHAR(1) NOT NULL,       -- 'S'
    origen      INTEGER NOT NULL,
    codi        INTEGER NOT NULL,
    no_cia      INTEGER NOT NULL,
    num_dcca    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    no_aprof    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    no_compta   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    cod_exp     INTEGER NOT NULL        -- 99609
);

CREATE TABLE table3
(
    no_cev      INTEGER NOT NULL,
    num_dcca    INTEGER NOT NULL,       -- 1
    codest      INTEGER NOT NULL        -- 76695
);

LOAD FROM "table1.unl" INSERT INTO table1;
LOAD FROM "table2.unl" INSERT INTO table2;
LOAD FROM "table3.unl" INSERT INTO table3;
```

The annotations indicate the value specified in the query for that column; they helped guide the construction of the sample data.

Three sample data files in the Informix (pipe-separated values) UNLOAD format are:

**`table1.unl`**

```
2|Literal value 1|100
2|Literal value 2|123
2|Literal value 3|134
2|Literal value 4|145
```

**`table2.unl`**

```
2|2345|100|222|333|S|444|555|666|777|888|999|99609
2|2346|123|223|333|S|444|555|666|776|888|999|99609
2|2347|134|224|333|S|444|555|666|775|888|999|99609
2|2348|145|225|333|S|444|555|666|774|888|999|99609
1|2345|100|225|333|S|444|555|666|773|888|999|99609
2|2340|123|226|333|S|444|555|666|772|888|999|99609
3|2347|134|227|333|S|444|555|666|771|888|999|99609
2|2350|145|228|333|S|444|555|666|770|888|999|99609
```

**`table3.unl`**

```
2345|1|76695
2346|1|88776
2347|2|76695
2348|1|76695
```

#### Result of query using Informix-style OUTER join

Assuming that the stray early semicolon in the original query should be an AND (that matches what is written in the proposed Oracle query), removing the two empty string result columns, and removing the superfluous level of parentheses, then the original query looks like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       table3.no_cev,   
       table1.literal,   
       table1.colid,   
       table2.repid,   
       table2.valor,   
       table2.indicador,   
       table2.origen,   
       table2.codi,  
       table2.no_cia,
       table2.num_dcca,
       table2.no_aprof,
       table2.no_compta
  FROM table1,   
       OUTER table2,   
       table3  
 WHERE (table1.colid  = table2.colid) AND  
       (table1.grupid  = table2.grupid) AND  
       (table3.no_cev  = table2.no_cev) AND  
       (table1.grupid = 2) AND  
       (table2.cod_exp = 99609) AND  
       (table2.indicador = 'S') AND  
       (table3.num_dcca = 1)    AND
       (table3.codest = 76695);
```

On the sample data shown, using Informix 12.10.FC6 running on a MacBook Pro with macOS 10.14.6 Mojave (not that the o/s is likely to be a factor in the results), this produces:

```
2345|Literal value 1|100|222|333|S|444|555|666|777|888|999
2345|Literal value 2|123|||||||||
2345|Literal value 3|134|||||||||
2345|Literal value 4|145|||||||||
2348|Literal value 1|100|||||||||
2348|Literal value 2|123|||||||||
2348|Literal value 3|134|||||||||
2348|Literal value 4|145|225|333|S|444|555|666|774|888|999
```

Why, you ask?  Good question!  The Informix old-style OUTER join is a complex critter, and doesn't necessarily have a simple translation to modern standard SQL (and hence to Oracle, etc).  You can find some description of the way it works at [Complex Outer Joins](https://ronsavage.github.io/SQL/outer-joins.html).

There are two groups of tables — `table1` and `table3` are the dominant tables, and `table2` is the only OUTER table here.  This means that Informix processes `table1` and `table3` using inner join, and then outer joins the result with `table2`.  Since there is no direct join between `table1` and `table3`, the result is a cartesian product of the two tables — each of the 4 rows in `table1` is joined with each of the 4 rows in `table3`, yielding 16 rows.  However, the filter conditions eliminate the rows from `table3` where `no_cev` is 2346 and 2347.  All the remaining 8 rows will be preserved, regardless of the results of the outer join operation.  Now the rows are outer joined with `table2`.  The rows with (`no_cev`, `colid`) of (2345, 100) and (2348, 145) have matching rows in `table3` where the data satisfies the conditions in the WHERE clause.  The other rows don't have such matching rows so the columns from `table2` for those rows are 'all NULL'.  As I said, it is weird — contorted.  And explaining is hard work!

#### A first approximation using standard SQL

This query is a moderate approximation to a direct translation of the Informix query:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
           t3.no_cev,   
           t1.literal,   
           t1.colid,   
           t2.repid,   
           t2.valor,   
           t2.indicador,   
           t2.origen,   
           t2.codi,  
           t2.no_cia,
           t2.num_dcca,
           t2.no_aprof,
           t2.no_compta
      FROM      table1 AS t1
     INNER JOIN table3 AS t3 ON 1 = 1
      LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t3.no_cev = t2.no_cev
                            AND t1.colid = t2.colid
                            AND t1.grupid = t2.grupid
     WHERE t1.grupid = 2
       AND t2.cod_exp = 99609
       AND t2.indicador = 'S'
       AND t3.num_dcca = 1
       AND t3.codest = 76695;
```

The output is:

```
2345|Literal value 1|100|222|333|S|444|555|666|777|888|999
2348|Literal value 4|145|225|333|S|444|555|666|774|888|999
```

This is missing the rows with 'null values'.

#### Achieving the same result using standard INNER and OUTER joins

We can collect those rows by looking for rows where one of the columns in `table2` is null (because they're either all null or none null — because the columns are qualified NOT NULL):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       t3.no_cev,   
       t1.literal,   
       t1.colid,   
       t2.repid,   
       t2.valor,   
       t2.indicador,   
       t2.origen,   
       t2.codi,  
       t2.no_cia,
       t2.num_dcca,
       t2.no_aprof,
       t2.no_compta
  FROM      table1 AS t1
 INNER JOIN table3 AS t3 ON 1 = 1
  LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t3.no_cev = t2.no_cev
                        AND t1.colid = t2.colid
                        AND t1.grupid = t2.grupid
 WHERE t1.grupid = 2
   AND ((t2.cod_exp = 99609 AND t2.indicador = 'S') OR t2.cod_exp IS NULL)
   AND t3.num_dcca = 1
   AND t3.codest = 76695;
```

This yields the output:

```
2345|Literal value 1|100|222|333|S|444|555|666|777|888|999
2345|Literal value 2|123|||||||||
2345|Literal value 3|134|||||||||
2345|Literal value 4|145|||||||||
2348|Literal value 1|100|||||||||
2348|Literal value 2|123|||||||||
2348|Literal value 3|134|||||||||
2348|Literal value 4|145|225|333|S|444|555|666|774|888|999
```

This is the same as the original old-style Informix OUTER join query.

#### Tejash's proposed solution

The SQL in [Tejash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11565629/tejash)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57655616/15168) ([revision 1](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57655616/revisions)) yields, on the same data:

```
2345|Literal value 1|100|222|333|S|\ |\ |444|555|666|777|888|999
2348|Literal value 4|145|225|333|S|\ |\ |444|555|666|774|888|999
```

The backslash-space values correspond to the empty strings — it's Informix's slightly peculiar way of encoding a zero-length non-null string.  It's an area where Oracle may well behave slightly differently, but it is tangential to the problem with the query.

Clearly, this is not the same result as the Informix query.  It's probably more reasonable; it works out of the box (I simply did copy'n'paste, quoted numbers and all, and it worked with no editing needed).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Informix `OUTER` syntax, so my answer may be wrong. The `WHERE` clause, however, lacking any relation between table1 and table3 suggests that this is just a cross join of table1 and table3 and then an outer join of table2.

One way to write this:

```
select t3.no_cev, t1.literal, t1.colid, t2.*
from table1 t1
cross join table3 t3
left join table2 t2 on  t2.colid = t1.colid
                    and t2.grupid = t1.grupid
                    and t2.no_cev = t3.no_cev
                    and t2.cod_exp = 2
                    and t2.indicador = 'S'
where t1.grupid = 2
and t3.num_dcca = 1
and t3.codest = 76695;
```

Another is:

```
with t1 as (select * from table1 where grupid = 2)
   , t2 as (select * from table1 where grupid = 2 and cod_exp = 2 and indicador = 'S')
   , t3 as (select * from table3 where num_dcca = 1 and codest = 76695)
select t3.no_cev, t1.literal, t1.colid, t2.*
from t1
cross join t3
left join t2 on t2.colid = t1.colid and t2.no_cev = t3.no_cev;
```

Above queries are standard SQL and supported by Oracle as of version 9i I think.